How do I install Transformations in QGIS
I have recently reinstalled QGIS LTR (3.34.9) using the OSGeo4W installer.
The standard CRS I use is EPSG:27700 (British National Grid or OSGB36)
I also often include Google imagery in my project file, which is EPSG:3857.
But creating a new project, when I go to add a transformation file I not longer see a list of transformation files, nor do I get prompted to install one. I have copied the relevant OSTN158_NTv2 files into the folder C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj, and restarted QGIS, but I still don't see them, as screeenshot below.

For an existing project, the transformation files are present (Project_Propoerties_Transformations), as this screenshot.
How can I configure QGIS so the best available transformnations from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:27700 are available in all new projects.


Instead of adding your  transformations to Project Properties which is a per project setting, add them to Settings-Options-CRS and Transforms-Coordinate Transforms which is a global setting.

Then when starting a new project, that transformation will automatically be used.


That is where I am trying to add them. The screenshot from project properties was showing how the transformation settings were set in existing projects.  My problem is I can't set transformations for new projects, either in global or project settings.

Works for me in QGIS 3.38

Not a very useful comment. I'm not reporting a bug, I'm asking how I might fix an issue I have!

I answered your question as asked and showed what works for me. If you are already setting globally, then your question was unclear.  Try a new profile.
